# Default Cordova 3 datepicker not initializing value

Tags: android, cordova, datepicker

I'm using a more recent version of Cordova (3.4.0) and I'm having trouble with what appears to be a default date picker.  Here's a simple scenario:

1. Create a new cordova project using the CLI.
2. Modify the index.html to include `<input type="date"/>`
3. Run it on my HTC phone (running Android v 4.4.2)
4. Click on the date input control...

In the past (prior to me upgrading cordova and my android os) clicking the date field would fall back on the standard android browser HTML5 date picker (if browser handled it).  Now, it opens what appears to be a default Android SDK datepicker with "Set" "Clear" and "Cancel" options. (I'd post a picture but don't have the required rep points yet...)

**Note that this is without any plugins included.**  This would be fine with me however, the picker never initializes to the input's value - but instead always to today's date.  Even if you use the picker to set the date to a different date and then re-open the picker, it reverts back to today.

I'm guessing this is a defect in how Cordova fires up the picker, but I can't determine how/where to fix it.

Also I realize I could use a custom datepicker plugin, but that creates it's own problems e.g. both pickers (default and custom plugin) being opened on click/focus.

Any suggestions on how to address this?